# SQL ORACLE Creating a column name with using htf (hypertext functions)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm working on SQL ORACLE DATABASE and I create a table than going into foor loob and working with htf for convert table to html formate.

```
set define off

create table show_mail (id number, data varchar2(25));

insert into show_mail values(101, 'one hundred & one')
insert into show_mail values(202, 'two hundred & two')
insert into show_mail values(303, 'three hundred & three')


declare
v_html varchar2(32767);
begin
v_html := htf.tableopen;
for i in (select * from show_mail) loop
v_html := v_html || htf.tableopen('border="1px"');
v_html := v_html || htf.tablerowopen;
v_html := v_html || htf.tableheader('ID');
v_html := v_html || htf.tableheader('DATA');
v_html := v_html || htf.tablerowclose;
v_html := v_html || htf.tablerowopen;
v_html := v_html || htf.tabledata(i.id);
v_html := v_html || htf.tabledata(htf.escape_sc(i.data));  
v_html := v_html || htf.tablerowclose;
v_html := v_html || htf.tableclose;
end loop;
v_html := v_html || htf.tableclose;
dbms_output.put_line(v_html);
end;
```

I use this code and the result like that;

```
ID  DATA
101 one hundred & one
ID  DATA
202 two hundred & two
ID  DATA
303 three hundred & three
```

Is it possible that only one column name and donot repeat it?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
DECLARE
    v_html VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEOPEN('border="1px"');
    v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEROWOPEN;
    v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEHEADER('ID');
    v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEHEADER('DATA');
    v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEROWCLOSE;
    FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM show_mail) LOOP
        v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEROWOPEN;
        v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEDATA(i.id);
        v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEDATA(HTF.ESCAPE_SC(i.data));  
        v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEROWCLOSE;
    END LOOP;
    v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLECLOSE;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_html);
end;
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you so much.